# How to resize a blob image that was retrieved from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

Hello and good day everyone! I am currently trying to figure out how to resize an image that I retrieved from the mysql database, so far this is what I have and it displays the image that was uploaded in the mysql database:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $rowID['companyImage'] ).'"/>';
```

From the code I currently have, is there a way I could resize the image I retrieve or is there another way to do it? Thanks! any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you simply trying to resize in html, or in PHP?

Comment: mostly php, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use PHP instead of HTML, I would recommend you look into using either PHP-GD or Imagick. Both of these libraries are well documented, and provide resizing images (from file, or from variable input)

Comment: <img height="" width="">